# Emberjs something like ajax request return in Helper

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, ember.js

Through much looking and trying, I believe there is no way to return a value from an ajax request in an Emberjs help.  (I hope I am wrong.)  I believe the reason is the whole ansyc callback thing.

So this is my dilemma;

I have a parent model A that has children of model B.  I would like to display the parent and the children together with some extra information.  The extra information is coming from an api call that is using some of model B's information.  I am not saving this extra information on model B, but I would like to display it.  So basically, I have something like this:

```
{{#each modelb in modela.modelbs}}
...
{{/each}}
```

I would love to be able to do something like:

```
{{#each modelb in modela.modelbs}}
  {{get-info modelb}}
{{/each}}
```

And it return the information that I am able to get from the api call.

I tried using a helper like I said before.  I tried putting some logic in the controller, but I can not isolate individual child models to create a computed property.  (plus I am not sure if a computerd property would help me, I think it needs a return statement, which puts me back in the same issue as a helper, and I do not think I can create a computed property on the child relationship.)  And while I have the extra information I need from the api call, I have no way to associate it with my child model B.

I figure I am not thinking about this problem in the 'ember way'.  Hopefully, there is a better way to go about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with.

In my route I write:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  //model is already loaded from parent route.
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    var modela = model; //just for clarity with the whole modela/modelb thing.
    modela.get('modelbs').forEach(function(modelb){
      $.ajax({
        //some ajax call using modelb's information.
      }).then(function(data){
        //extraInformation is not a model definted property on modelb, but I just added extraInformation as an index to modelb.
        modelb['extraInformation'] = data;
        controller.set('model', modela);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Then in my template I write:

```
{{#each modelb in modela.modelbs}}
  {{modelb.extraInformation}}
{{/each}}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, since you have the data, is when you make the call for a modelA or ModelB, attach an id of somesorts as a parameter to the call function, and return that with the call's callback. With the callback, you can call a function that will find the correct model to attach the data to?

for example:

```
var objs = [
    {id:1, info: "hi", extraInfo: ""},
    {id:2, info: "bye", extraInfo: ""}
];

for(var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++){
    getRelatedInfo("extraInfo", objs[i].id);
}

function getRelatedInfo(someParam, 1){
    // call
    // on success
    attachInfoToObj(result, 1);
}
function attachInfoToObj(data, id){
    for(var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++){
        if(objs[i].id === id){
           objs[i].extraInfo = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake!  Where do I put this? helper, controller, router? and how does this update my template?  If this is in a helper, I do not know where I would put the return (I think the helper needs to return something). If this in a controller, I do not know how I would set the property.

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but I think I can loop through my children models and just add an attribute to the children in the controller.  I think I tried something like this before I wrote this question, but looking at it again and changing somethings; I think it may work.  I will report back when I have time to implement it.

Comment: I can't help you out with best practices with Ember, sorry. I imagine the call would be done from the controller and the data put into the model you are showing. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Jake Rowsell, it is like what you said.  But, I just added an index to my modelb with the info I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get modelb's info in modela's afterModel hook. Example:

```
App.ModelaRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('modela', params.id);
  },
  afterModel: function(modela) {
    // Note: afterModel is called after modela is loaded

    // Iterate through modelbs
    modela.get('modelbs').foreach(function(modelb) {
      // Get current modelb's extra information by ajax. Note that this may result in *many* ajax requests - may be undesirable
      ajaxRequestForModelbInfo.done(function(response) {
        // Assign extra information to modelb's extraInformation property
        modelb.set('extraInformation', response);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

In the hbs template file:

```
{{#each modelb in modela.modelbs}}
  {{modelb.extraInformation}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks datchung. I could not use after model because when I try to 'set' the property that does not exist on the model, it gave me an error, which it should.  And when I tried to use the [] operator, it did not give me an error, but when I tried to display that info from the index in my template, it did not display anything.
I think the [] issue may have to do with [this](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-use-aftermodel-results-in-setupcontroller/6251)
In any event, I ended up putting my code in the setupController and adding an index to my modelb with the info I needed.